# More condition in awk; adding column according to condition

Tags: awk

How to add column 5 according to conditions for column 1?

input:

```
word2       1   2   3  
word3       5   6   2   
word2       8   9   6
word1       5   6   6
word5       7   8   8
word4       9   8   6

awk '{ if ( ( $1 ~ /word1/ {$5 == "0.0697") &&
            ( $1 ~ /word2/ {$5 == "0.0645") &&
            ( $1 ~ /word3/ {$5 == "0.0655") &&
            ( $1 ~ /word4/ {$5 == "0.0677") &&
            ( $1 ~ /word5/ {$5 == "0.0678") ) {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}}' input > output
```

Desired output
output:

```
word2       1   2   3   0.0645
word3       5   6   2   0.0655
word2       8   9   6   0.0645
word1       5   6   6   0.0697
word5       7   8   8   0.0678
word4       9   8   6   0.0677
```

Comment: What do you expect when the first column reads "word1word2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{ if( $1 ~ /word1/) {$5 = "0.0697"}
       else if ( $1 ~ /word2/) {$5 = "0.0645"}
       else if ( $1 ~ /word3/) {$5 = "0.0655"}
       else if ( $1 ~ /word4/) {$5 = "0.0677"}
       else if ( $1 ~ /word5/) {$5 = "0.0678"}
     }
{
   print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
}
'  Input_file
```

Or you could put `1` in place of `print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5` too in code like as follows:

```
awk '{ if( $1 ~ /word1/) {$5 = "0.0697"}
       else if ( $1 ~ /word2/) {$5 = "0.0645"}
       else if ( $1 ~ /word3/) {$5 = "0.0655"}
       else if ( $1 ~ /word4/) {$5 = "0.0677"}
       else if ( $1 ~ /word5/) {$5 = "0.0678"}
     }
1
'  Input_file
```

***Issues with OP's approach:***

`{$5 == "0.0697")`:

1- We shouldn't use `==` that is used for checking condition, instead use `=`.

2- Use `}` to close it while assigning values.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '$1 ~ /word1/ {$5 = "0.0697"};
     $1 ~ /word2/ {$5 = "0.0645"};
     $1 ~ /word3/ {$5 = "0.0655"};
     $1 ~ /word4/ {$5 = "0.0677"};
     $1 ~ /word5/ {$5 = "0.0678"}; 
     {print}' file
```

Output:

```
word2 1 2 3 0.0645
word3 5 6 2 0.0655
word2 8 9 6 0.0645
word1 5 6 6 0.0697
word5 7 8 8 0.0678
word4 9 8 6 0.0677
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic approach.  It should be fast, since you are not testing every line for all possible number, and its easy to expand.

```
awk 'BEGIN {split("0.0697 0.0645 0.0655 0.0677 0.0678",a," ")} {split($1,b,"[^0-9]+");print $0,a[b[2]]}' file
word2       1   2   3 0.0645
word3       5   6   2 0.0655
word2       8   9   6 0.0645
word1       5   6   6 0.0697
word5       7   8   8 0.0678
word4       9   8   6 0.0677
```

With this you could get numbers from a key file:

```
key="0.0697 0.0645 0.0655 0.0677 0.0678"
awk -v k="$key" 'BEGIN {split(k,a," ")}{split($1,b,"[^0-9]+");print $0,a[b[2]]}' file
word2       1   2   3 0.0645
word3       5   6   2 0.0655
word2       8   9   6 0.0645
word1       5   6   6 0.0697
word5       7   8   8 0.0678
word4       9   8   6 0.0677
```